# SOAP and Rest Webservice using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

I'm developing my first `Spring Boot` application containing both Soap and rest `webservice`.  I've to pass Request in url as a parameter. I'm able to pass request in URL for Rest service. Is it possible to send request in URL for `SOAP` `webservice`?

Comment: No. As `SOAP` requests are basically `POST` request which doesn't allow you to sent request data as part of a URL.

Comment: @arpit So we can send soap request only in XML format through SOAP UI tool, right?

Comment: Yes!, soap allow to send only xml

Comment: @Arpit Thank you. Is it possible to develop both SOAP and REST in single Application. 1. Rest: Passing parameter to an application through REST URL.      2. SOAP: Passing XML through SOAPUI to the same application by hitting SOAP URL of that application

Answer (score 2):

Ok I am not sure what are your intentions but about SOAP.

```
---------------                      ----------------
|             |   someMethodInvoke   |              |
|  Your API   | -------------------->| WEB Service  |
|             |<-------------------- |              |
---------------    someResult        ----------------
```

Now attending a communication with a WS you need firstly to have the schema of that API or the `.WSDL` from which you can generate Objects with which you will make the calls you need.

I am personally am using `JAXB` for generating `.java` classes from schema.

After for the call it self `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate` is the thing that gets the job done. You can use `marshalSendAndReceive`.

For example:

```
public class SomeService extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
     ObjectFactory oFactory = new ObjectFactory();

     public ExpectedResultObject someMethodInvoke(RequestObjectGeneratedFromSchema request){
            JAXBElement<ExpectedResultObject> response = (JAXBElement<ExpectedResultObject>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://yourURL.com", oFactory.createreRequestObjectGeneratedFromSchemaInputMessage(request));  
            return response.getValue();
     }
}
```

Firstly extend the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` so you can invoke the `getWebServiceTemplate()` which return just exactly what you need : `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`. Here is an example how you can use the `WebServiceTemplate`

Of course there are a lot of factors like security, connectivity and so on which maybe should be set. But that depends on the WS. But basicly that is all :

1. Generate .java classes from WSDL(schema)
2. Fill generated object with information
3. Use some WebServiceTemplate for calling the END point

Hope I gave you some directions.